# Powershell Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs Limits

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm using Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs from the AzureADPreview Module.
This cmdlet limits its output to 1000 lines.
I thought doing a workaround and ask it by User/Date filter.
It would work in my case but then I'm hitting a http429 error like this.

```
Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs 
Code: UnknownError
Message: Too Many Requests
InnerError:
  RequestId: fc532b20-baea-4f62-8b5a-f4714f86f0a9
  DateTimeStamp: Wed, 10 Nov 2021 14:40:35 GMT
HttpStatusCode: 429
HttpStatusDescription: Too Many Requests
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

I've seen techniques on how to query the number of request you can still make within a given time, but that was all when you launch http-requests. I suppose the module is masking that for us.

Does anybody know a technique on how to do this with this module ?

This is the code

```
Write-Output ("--- Get All AAD SignOns ---")
$filterDate = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f (get-date).AddDays(-30)
$TempFileName = $TempDir + $storageblobpath + $FileName + "AADSignOn.csv"
$usrCount     = 0
$logCount     = 0

ForEach ($user in $users) {
    $usrCount++
    $signons = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime ge $filterDate and userPrincipalName eq '$user.UserPrincipalName'" |
                Select-Object Id,CreatedDateTime,UserId,AppId,AppDisplayName,IpAddress,ClientAppUsed,IsInteractive,TokenIssuerType,ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds,
                    @{name='DeviceId';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceId} },
                    @{name='DeviceDisplayName';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.DisplayName} },
                    @{name='DeviceOperatingSystem';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem} },
                    @{name='DeviceBrowser';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.Browser} },
                    @{name='DeviceIsCompliant';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.IsCompliant} },
                    @{name='DeviceIsManaged';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.IsManaged} },
                    @{name='DeviceTrustType';expression={$_.DeviceDetail.TrustType} },
                    @{name='LocationCity';expression={$_.Location.City} },
                    @{name='LocationState';expression={$_.Location.State} },
                    @{name='LocationCountryOrRegion';expression={$_.Location.CountryOrRegion} }
    $signons | Export-Csv -Path $TempFileName -NoTypeInformation -Append

    $logCount += $signons.Count                   
    if ($usrCount % 200 -eq 0) {
        Write-Output ("Users {0}, {1} Logs so far" -f $usrCount, $logCount)
    }
}
```

Kr, Harry

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the error?

Comment: Code is added to the question

Comment: In your filter, you should use `$($user.UserPrincipalName)` rather than `$user.UserPrincipalName`. This is to prevent premature parsing of just `$user` in your string.

Comment: Please check this Github discussion it may help you : https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/337

Comment: Hello @Harry,If my answer is helpful for you, you can upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment with lasted `AzureADPreview` module and getting same error as you are getting.

With the latest module I've found this error appears only for certain log entries. For example, filter on a specific user UPN.

```
$signons = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime ge $filterDate and userPrincipalName eq '$user.UserPrincipalName'"
```

Tried with older module version like 2.0.2.85, 2.0.2.89, 2.0.2.105 but getting the same error.

**Note** : These PowerShell cmdlets currently only work with the Azure AD Preview Module. Please note that the preview module is not suggested for production use.

Please check same it has mentioned over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-powershell-reporting)

I have tried on specific user filter on `userDisplayName` for that it has working.

```
 $signons = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt 2021-10-18 and userDisplayName eq 'MOD Administrator'" |
               Select-Object Id,CreatedDateTime,UserId,AppId,AppDisplayName,IpAddress,ClientAppUsed,IsInteractive,TokenIssuerType,ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds
                  
Write-Output ("--- All Okay ---")
    $signons | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\AzureAD\AADSignOn.txt' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

[image]

Output--
[image]

But Same is not running for UPN and getting error.

[image]

Loop is not completing for all the users.

[image]

Many of the users has reported the same issue went through this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/337) discussion as well but didn’t get the proper solution would suggest you to please reach out to [MS support](https://support.microsoft.com/) team.

Comment: I joined the club requesting a 'better' solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error from looping through a set of users in my environment. Now i've not tested this extensively, but adding a delay to each request seems to bypass this error in my case at least.

I simply added `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500` to the end of each request. Granted my user-base wasn't that large so this might add significant time to your loop, but the errors did not occur afterwards.

Edit: Running a try/catch statement and only delaying upon error i found to be a faster way than a consistent delay.

```
    try {
        $UPN = $entry.Trim()
        Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$UPN'" | select UserPrincipalName,CreatedDateTime -Last 1 | Out-File -FilePath $login_file -Append
    }
    catch {
        $UPN = $entry.Trim()
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
        Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$UPN'" | select UserPrincipalName,CreatedDateTime -Last 1 | Out-File -FilePath $login_file -Append
    }
```