# Powershell Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs not returning as many logs as expected

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, audit-logging, azure-storage-account

I'm using Powershell to grab SignInLogs from Azure AD. As far as I understand, SignInLogs are archived for a rolling period of 7 days in Azure. However, when I use this method I only get 960 individual sign in logs back. There should be a lot more if it's going back 7 days (I looked into it and there are sometimes over 960 new sign-ins about every 10 minutes). Is there a limit to the number of logs you can pull with Powershell this way? Or, is there a way to specify a greater historical period for getting the logs?

Here's the Powershell command:

```
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId me@company.com 
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs
```

Edit: I've tried specifying an earlier start date but still getting the same number of logs:

```
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId me@company.com 
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt 2022-02-03"
```

Comment: Can you try using AzureADPreview Module instead of AzureAD module as mentioned in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/432)

Comment: First Uninstall AzureAD and then Install AzureADPreview

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turns out I only had AzureADPreview Module installed and never Azure AD. The version of AzureADPreview is 2.0.2.149

Comment: was the issue resolved?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915417/powershell-get-azureadauditsigninlogs-limits

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing issue. Couple of users have reported the same issue @ [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/337). Would suggest you to please reach out to [MS support](https://support.microsoft.com/) team.